# Prove that $[ab]=[[a][b]]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a,b,N\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $N>0$. Prove that $[ab]=[[a][b]]$, where $[x]$ denotes the remainder of $x$ after division by $N$.

Here's my attempt:

*Proof.* Since $x\equiv{[x]}_c\pmod c$, we know $a\equiv{[a]} \pmod{N}$ and $b\equiv{[b]} \pmod{N}$. By Proposition 1.3.4 in the book,
$$ab\equiv{[a]}{[b]} \pmod N$$
Applying the first theorem we used to each side of the equation, we have
$${[ab]}={[{[a]}{[b]}]}$$
QED.

I think the last line in my proof is wrong. I tried combining these two statements:

1. $ab\equiv[ab]\pmod{N}$
2. ${[a]}{[b]}\equiv[{[a]}{[b]}]\pmod{N}$

But what makes me hesitate is that the statements have *equivalence*, not equality. I'm new to number theory and do not know how to handle equivalence.

Can you offer any help? I am looking for hints, not complete answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since the remainder of something upon division by $N$ is an element of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,N-1\}$, it is *sufficient* to show that $[ab] \equiv [[a][b]] \mod N$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$(0\le[ab]<N )\land (0\le \left[[a][b]\right]<N)\implies \left\lvert[ab]-\left[[a][b]\right]\right\rvert<N$

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use congruences, personally, because $x \equiv x + N$ would confuse me.
The answer by user133281 isn't wrong, but I find it easier to do the following.

By the division algorithm, there are integers $k_i$ such that:

$[ab] = ab - Nk_{ab}$

$[a] = a - Nk_a$

$[b] = b - Nk_b$

where $0 \le [x] < N$

These are *equalities*, so you can use all the equality rules you're familiar with.